# Repeatedly getting error for 'singular matrix' in implementation of Newton Raphson in MLE estimation of logistic function

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling

I am using Python 3, and am trying to estimate the parameters corresponding to maximizing the likelihood function for a logistic regression model; but unfortunately my code repeatedly returns a 'singular matrix' error in the implementation of the Newton-Raphson procedure. The full code is below, with the part corresponding to the Newton Raphson procedure clearly marked.

I suspect that it may be connected with the Hessian no longer being positive semi-definite (my code prints out 'Hessian not positive semi-definite!' when the Choleski decomposition fails.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Define link function here
def g(z):
    g=1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    return g

#For producing y data values given true paramters theta and number of covariates
def logit_data(n,p, theta):
    #Define parameters

    #1)Number of covariates
    p_i = p+1  #with intercept
    p_i=np.int(p_i)

    #2) m as correct data type
    n=np.int(n)

    #4)Specify parameter valueas to be estimated
    theta=np.reshape(theta, (p_i,1))

    #5)Define distribution from which covariate values are drawn i.i.d., and initiate data values
    X=np.zeros((n,p_i))
    X[:,0]=1    #intercept
    mean=0
    sigma=1.5

    X[:,1:]=np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(n,p))


    #6)Produce y values treating y as a Bernoulli variable with p=g(X*theta)
    r=np.random.uniform(0,1,n)
    r=np.reshape(r, (len(r),1))
    htrue=g(X.dot(theta))
    y=htrue-r
    y[y>=0]=1
    y[y<0]=0

    return X, y





#Newton Raphson implementation
def NewtonRaphson(X,y):
    ##NOTE: All functions negloglikelihood, gradf, hessian, return the -ve of the log likelihood function,
    #its gradient and its hessian respectively, to use NR method to minimise f (rather than maximise l)

    #Define log likelihood function to be maximised
    def negloglikelihood(y,h):
        l= y.transpose() @ np.log(h) + (1-y).transpose() @ np.log(1-h)
        f=-l
        return f

    #Define gradient of log likelihood function
    def gradf(y, h, X):
        a=(y-h).transpose()
        gradl= np.matmul(a,X)
        grad_f=-gradl
        return grad_f

    #Define second derivative (Hessian) of log likelihood function
    def hessian(h, X):
        D=np.identity(len(h))*(np.matmul(h,(1-h).transpose()))
        H=-X.transpose() @ D @ X
        Hf=-H
        return Hf

    #Minimise f=-l

    #Initiate theta and probability parameter h
    thetaEst=np.random.uniform(-5,10,(p+1,1))

    eta=np.matmul(X,thetaEst)
    h=g(eta)

    while not (gradf(y,h,X)==0).all():
        H=hessian(h,X)
        print(H)
        try:
            np.linalg.cholesky(H)
        except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
            print('Hessian not positive semi-definite!')

        h=g(np.matmul(X,thetaEst))  
        delta=np.linalg.solve(hessian(h,X), np.reshape(gradf(y,h,X),(6,1)))

        while negloglikelihood(y, h) < negloglikelihood(y, g(np.matmul(X,thetaEst+delta))):
            delta=0.5*delta

        thetaEst=thetaEst+delta

    return thetaEst









#Main control

#1)Sample numbers to test for erros in beta, as powers of 10.
npowers=np.arange(1,3,0.5)
n=np.power(10,npowers)


#2)Number of independent covariates
p=5


#3)True theta to be estimated (parameter values)
theta=np.asarray([1,1.2,1.1,0.8,0.9,1.3])


#4)#Initiate arrays to store estimates of theta (and errors) computed at specified sample numbers N
Thetas=np.zeros((len(npowers),p+1))
Errors=np.zeros((len(npowers),p+1))


#5)Obtain random covariate values from specified distribution, and corresponding y values using true theta
#plus gaussian noise term.
X,y = logit_data(n[-1],p,theta)


#6)Calulcate cumulative means for given n values, for the theta estimates
for ind,N in enumerate(n):
    N=np.int(N)
    thetaTemp=NewtonRaphson(X[0:N,:],y[0:N])
    Thetas[ind,:] = np.reshape(thetaTemp,6)



#7)Calculate true erros 
Errors=Thetas-theta.transpose()
absError=np.abs(Errors)
nerror=Errors*np.sqrt(n)[:,np.newaxis]


#8)Save data as csv


#9)Plots
fig=plt.figure()
for i in range(p+1):
    plt.plot(npowers, np.log10(absError[:,i]))

fig.suptitle('log10(AbsError) against log10(Number of samples) for error in maximum lieklihood estimator in gaussian model')
plt.xlabel('log_10(Number of sample data points)')
plt.ylabel('log_10(Absolute Error)')

fig.savefig('gaussianerrors.png')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: my estimates of Theta also seem to be diverging terribly! I am now aborting the NR function and returning the estimate of Theta as-is in the case of singular matrix. The estimates of theta I am getting are on the order 10^230, though the actual values are all of order unity!

Comment: Looking a bit more closely at the prints out of my Hessian, it may be just that my implementation has converged super fast, and the values in the Hessian are too small for the inverse. I'm seeing values on order 10^-7